# Send funds from a specific address with bitcoinj

Tags: wallet, bitcoinj

I have two addresses in my wallet. 
I use one of them as a buffer and clients can receive money only from that address.
How can I send money from a specific address?

Comment: Mind if I ask why you think you want to do this?